# An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, adt, eclipse-juno

I have just installed the following setup for mobile development with Cocos2d and encountered the following error, almost every time I restarted Eclipse:
"An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update". java.lang.NullPointerException"
Afterwards, nothing would work.

I still haven't found what's the cause of this error (BUT, I have a workaround, see below), and also searched for it in the net and didn't find anything related to my environment, which is as follows:

1. Win7 64bit
2. adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 (Eclipse Juno)
3. android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64
4. jdk-8u25-windows-x64

I am posting this since I have found a workaround to this annoying sh*tty error which I have wasted days on importing and creating new projects every time it appeared, most of the time after I closed and opened Eclipse.

-------- Error Workaround -----------
The error is on .cproject file located in proj.android directory. Seems like Eclipse or some plugin causes some malformation in this file.
I did a diff between a good .cproject file and a bad one which causes this annoying error.
Below are the lines that need to be removed from your .cproject file every time you encounter this error (and then restart Eclipse, all should be fine)

I hope this would be fixed soon - my guess is it probably happens only on 64bit.. don't know why I didn't install the 32bit and saved all that lost time in the first place... :/

Hope this helps.
Please feel free to add yor notes and thoughts, or even tell me if I did something wrong (or stupid..) since i'm kinda new with this ADT environment.

```
<cconfiguration id="0.1230402123.1377291156">
        <storageModule buildSystemId="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.configurationDataProvider" id="0.1230402123.1377291156" moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings" name="Debug">
            <externalSettings/>
            <extensions>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.VCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GmakeErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CWDLocator" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GCCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GASErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GLDErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
            </extensions>
```

--- SOME MORE XML ---

```
<autodiscovery enabled="true" problemReportingEnabled="true" selectedProfileId=""/>
    <scannerConfigBuildInfo instanceId="0.1230402123">
        <autodiscovery enabled="true" problemReportingEnabled="true" selectedProfileId=""/>
    </scannerConfigBuildInfo>
```

Comment: <personal opinion>  Eclipse is a bug ridden, committee designed sorry piece of software.  Try Android Studio instead, or anything from JetBrains </personal opinion>

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Since i'm using Cocos2d environment and C++, I understand that Android Studio does not support it yet. But it seems it may support it in the future..

Comment: Doh, I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: Android Studio Supports C++ since Version 1.3, so there might be a chance you can make it work. Its worth a try, everything will be so much easier and fluffy if you get it to work. http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/05/good-news-for-game-devs-android-studio-1-3-supports-androids-cc-ndk/